# Path to generated Visual Studio solution file from CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I want to know the path to the generated Visual Studio .sln solution file from CMakeLists.txt so that I can create a custom target that takes that file as an argument.

Is there a variable or function to obtain this information?

Comment: By default this should be placed in the build directory of the binary dir corresponding to the file. There is a way of obtaining this directory, but I'm pretty sure this is an XY problem. What are you trying to do with this solution? Assuming you want to build the solution or a specific target from it from another cmake project adding other project as subdirectory may be an option; This would make the target available in the project and open up some convenient ways of accessing info via generator expressions; another option would be using `cmake --build binary_dir` to build the solution...

Comment: the use case that motivated this question was adding a custom target for cppcheck without switching from MSVC generator to ninja.
cppcheck needs the .sln (or individual .vcxproj files)

Comment: `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.sln` works for now, but it won't necessarily be true for all CMake projects, will it?

Comment: Searching the cmake docs of the most recent release for `sln` unfortunately turns up only a single match (plus release notes): [`VS_STARTUP_PROJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VS_STARTUP_PROJECT.html?highlight=sln) and the content on this page does not contain any info about the name of the `sln`. I don't know about any properties/variables that would allow you to specify the solution name. For now the path you mentioned seems to be the best solution (unless you want to do a search for `.sln` files in the binary dir when executing your target).

Comment: Perhaps there's a Visual Studio Macro that could be used in your custom command though... (`... COMMAND cppcheck "--project=\$(SolutionPath)" ...`???)

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work: `cppcheck: Failed to open project ''.`